# Group by - Apply different filters for different groups

Tags: sql

**Query 1 -**

```
select rend, pay, count(*) from payer
where pay = '1'
group by rend, pay
```

**Query 2 -**

```
select rend, count(*) from payer
where pay = '2'
or 
(
pay = '3' AND model_code IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' )
)
group by rend
```

**Combined query -**

If I combine the queries like below, I get the correct counts for the first query because it does not have any additional filters. How do I apply the filters in the second query to the below query so they don't apply to `pay_type = 1` which is used in `Query 1`. I am basically looking to combine these two queries into a single query, so I don't have to write multiple cte's for every `pay` that has a where clause.

```
select rend, pay, count(*) from payer
group by rend, pay
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result. The question looks interesting.

Comment: Yes, please provide an example of the desired result. Do you intend to return the `pay` column even though it isn't included in Query 2? Otherwise, why wouldn't `select rend, pay, count(*) from payer
where pay = '1'
or
pay = '2'
or 
(
pay = '3' AND model_code IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' )
)
group by rend, pay` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
select rend, pay, count(*)
from payer
where case when pay = '1' then 1
           when pay = '2' then 1
           when pay = '3' and model_code in ('MGD', 'MEDI') then 1 
         = 1
group by rend, pay;
```

Comment: Yes looking through this I realized this doesn't solve my problem. I will add more context in the question to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply doing this?

```
select rend, max(pay), count(*) from payer
where pay in ('1', '2') or
      (pay = '3' and model_code in ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' )
      )
group by rend;
```

It is unclear what you want for the second column for the second query.